# Deletion of comments?

Tags: support, comments

I made a comment -- superficially flippant, perhaps, but in fact carefully constructed given the context -- [to this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1823/199). However, it appears to have been deleted, but I can't be sure because I never saw any notification of the deletion. Is that normal, or should one see a notice (and reason) for a comment deletion?

Comment: Hmm, that link doesn't seem to point to the answer I'm referring to. It's one of FaithfulBuddhist's two answers; the one to which @yuttadhammo has added a comment beginning "just the sort of answer we're looking for ..."

Comment: I deleted it... the comment said: `This is a non-comment.` Did you really think that comment added something to the discussion?

Comment: Yes. It was an example of the same kind of position taken by "non-buddhists". I was "showing", where "saying" is difficult to impossible, what "non-buddhism" is. I admit there was a touch of whimsy about it, but I was being serious.

Comment: What's wrong with just saying, "A non-Buddhist comment would be something like 'this is not a comment.'"? I may be dense, but I didn't see it as showing anything, except maybe snark. But then again, I'm not sure I really understand non-Buddhism in the way you do.

Comment: Leave it deleted. Neither it, nor (IMO) non-buddhism, is worth any more attention :-)

Comment: Bleh, I just put it back thinking I was being a jerk. No need to delete stuff that people feel adds to the conversation unless it gets flagged, right?

Comment: OK, well given that you have, I'll answer your question above. The reason I didn't just make your suggested statement was because I wanted to give a statement that was itself internally problematic (as the NBs say XB is), and having little or no "content" or "truth" (as FaithfulBuddhist claimed of NB). It was in the spirit of the Epimenides paradox, even Magritte's "Ceci n'est pas une pipe". BTW I notice that we've actually now been mentioned on the [old home page](http://speculativenonbuddhism.com) of NB. But as I said, for me I'm at the end of my limited interest in the whole thing.

Comment: You're famous ;) I'm still not convinced that we want such clever comments on the site - giving an example of something seems a little too smarmy (in another context I'd applaud it, but on SE?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't normally see notifications of deletion. Comments are frequently deleted on SE websites as a matter of bookkeeping, especially +1s etc.